# Compiling error with ACE lib on Slackware 14.2 64 bit

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, ace, slackware

I'm trying to compile ACE lib but I have errors compiling.

My Linux system is Slackware 14.2 64 bit

The lib is ACE version 6.1.4 (the version that I need to compile)

Before to post this I have followed all the steps for to build ACE from [ACE web](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/DOC_ROOT/ACE/ACE-INSTALL.html#aceinstall).

How to compile this lib?

This is the error:

```
In file included from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/OS_NS_Thread.h:32,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Guard_T.h:26,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Free_List.cpp:7,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Free_List.h:142,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Malloc_T.h:26,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Local_Name_Space.h:20,
             from Local_Name_Space.cpp:3:
/home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/os_include/os_sched.h:47:6: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef struct cpu_set_t cpu_set_t’
} cpu_set_t;
  ^~~~~~~~~

In file included from /usr/include/sched.h:44,
             from /usr/include/pthread.h:23,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/os_include/os_pthread.h:51,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/OS_NS_Thread.h:31,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Guard_T.h:26,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Free_List.cpp:7,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Free_List.h:142,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Malloc_T.h:26,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Local_Name_Space.h:20,
             from Local_Name_Space.cpp:3:
/usr/include/bits/cpu-set.h:42:3: nota: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct cpu_set_t cpu_set_t’
 } cpu_set_t;

In file included from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/TSS_T.h:261,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Singleton.h:24,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Service_Gestalt.h:30,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Service_Object.h:27,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Naming_Context.h:25,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Local_Name_Space_T.h:25,
             from /home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/Local_Name_Space.h:128,
             from Local_Name_Space.cpp:3:
/home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/TSS_T.cpp: En la función miembro ‘void ACE_TSS_Guard<ACE_LOCK>::init_key()’:
/home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/ace/TSS_T.cpp:357:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘ACE_Thread::keycreate(ACE_thread_key_t*, void (*)(void*), void*)’
                      (void *) this);
                                   ^
make[1]: *** [/home/cyneo/Downloads/ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/rules.local.GNU:189: .shobj/Local_Name_Space.o] Error 1
```

I have found this but I can't get doing working for me:

https://bugs.gentoo.org/638606

https://638606.bugs.gentoo.org/attachment.cgi?id=532828

Edit:

I have tried to compile ACE 6.5.0 too, but I get this error:

```
during GIMPLE pass: wrestrict
En la función miembro ‘virtual int ACE_Configuration_Heap::open_section(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, const ACE_TCHAR*, int, ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&)’:
en pp_format, en pretty-print.c:1378
ACE_Configuration_Heap::open_section (const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key& base,
```

Comment: Looks you gcc version is buggy, can you upgrade to a newer gcc version?

Comment: I have the last upgrade of gcc : (GCC) 8.1.1 20180626 anyway i fixed the problem, thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with ACE but didn't have the option to upgrade it. I managed to solve the conflicting declaration problem by adding following in ace/config.h and recompiling ACE.

```
#ifndef __cpu_set_t_defined
#define __cpu_set_t_defined
#endif //!__cpu_set_t_defined
```

You may ask why does this work? Well, if you get this error, it means that glibc has declared `cpu_set_t` but it didn't define `__cpu_set_t_defined`, which ACE had expected. Therefore, ACE tried to declare `cpu_set_t` as well, and the error occurs. 
So, by defining `__cpu_set_t_defined`, you tell ACE not to declare `__cpu_set_t_defined` again.

But please keep in mind that this is just a workaround and should be used only if you don't have the option to update ACE.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Finally i have compiled ACE 6.5.0 for Slackware 14.2 64 bit.
It needed add some parameters in "ACE_wrappers/include/makeinclude/platform_macros.GNU" :

```
INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr 
INSTALL_LIB=lib64
stl=1
gl=1
ssl=1
buildbits=64
dynamic_loader=1
insure=0
optimize=0
static_stdlibs=0
include $(ACE_ROOT)/include/makeinclude/platform_linux.GNU
```

Comment: Would recommend to try to compile with TCPU and archmodelflag removed

Comment: i have recompiled and it gone fine :), i reedit with the new parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This version of ACE is ancient, upgrading to [ACE 6.5.0](http://download.dre.vanderbilt.edu) fixes this.

Comment: I hace tried to compile ACE 6.5.0 too but i get this error :  during GIMPLE pass: wrestrict En la función miembro ‘virtual int ACE_Configuration_Heap::open_section(const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&, const ACE_TCHAR*, int, ACE_Configuration_Section_Key&)’: en pp_format, en pretty-print.c:1378 ACE_Configuration_Heap::open_section (const ACE_Configuration_Section_Key& base,

Comment: Looks you gcc version is buggy, can you upgrade your gcc version?

Comment: I have the last upgrade of gcc : (GCC) 8.1.1 20180626    anyway i fixed the problem, thanks for answer :)